# Is there a process to continue with a method after another one has been invoked AND completed?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I would like to control the flow of information into a C# plugin I am writing for Battlefield 4. From my plugin, I must send a command to the Battlefield 4 server. There is a method in the plugin manager which I can't touch that will receive the response (from a command I sent via the plugin) from the server and pass back the information to the event as parameters.

If no information is controlled, plugins can run code without restraint and commands from external sources (users, other plugins) can tamper with normal plugin execution.

```
        private void PerformProconTasks(params string[] actions) //A list of commands that will be processed.
        {
            foreach(var action in actions)
            {   
                var command = action.Split(' ');
                RegisterEvents(this.GetType().Name, InvocationDictionary[command[0]]); //The event will not be ignored by registering it now.
                ProconPluginEXT.ExecuteCommand(this, command);    //Sends command to the Battlefield 4 server

                //Problem: We want to wait for the invoked event to complete before continuing with the loop. We do not know when the invoked event will occur neither do we know how long it will take for it to finish.
            }
        }

        public override void On3dSpotting(bool isEnabled) //This is an example: an event that is invoked after the server responds (true or false) to the command: "vars.3dSpotting".
        {
    this.ExecuteCommand("procon.protected.pluginconsole.write", "^6Hello from the other side!");
        }
```

I would call the next command from the event but I believe this approach limits the uses for that function. Anything about the event can change (return type, access, other modifiers) except the name and the parameters.

I'm just wondering if I can halt `performprocontasks` until the corresponding event is finished, even when I don't know when the corresponding event will fire and have no access to the data it will receive.

**Edit:** ExecuteCommand is void unfortunately and does not directly invoke On3dSpotting.
All it does is send the action/command to the battlefield server. The PluginManager is what invokes On3dSpotting and it is unreachable.

Also, the issue I am having with tasks is that I do not know when to create the task since I do not know when the event will fire and how to hook up the task to something that will exist eventually.

**Thanks**

Comment: Doesn't `ExecuteCommand` return a `Task<T>` or use some other promise/future-based pattern?

Comment: What is the execution-path from `ExecuteCommand` to `On3dSpotting`? (i.e. does `ExecuteCommand` invoke `On3dSpotting` on the same thread while execution is inside `ExecuteCommand`?) If so then you can probably hack something together with a `TaskCompletionSource` if you know it's safe to use `async` - otherwise use the thread-pool with synchronization primitives.

Comment: `.ContinueWith`

Comment: ExecuteCommand is void unfortunately and does not directly invoke On3dSpotting. 
All it does is send the action/command to the server.

I'm adding more clarification to the question.

Comment: @Dai the event will not always be fired on the same thread unfortunately.